# django 1.7 migration file cannot use User methods

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, migration, django-1.7

I'm working on a project using django 1.7. I made a migration file and want to use User method such as `user.get_first_name()`, and it returns

```
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'
```

I import `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, but i don't think it's the reason.

Btw, I use pdb to debug it. I found I can use user's file, such as `user.first_name`, `user.username`, but all methods of User return has no attribute.

Did I miss something? Or I mis-use something?

Comment: That methods are for a User model instances. Where do you are calling?

Comment: I use an user instance called user to call. user.get_full_name()

Comment: I have a similar problem. I wanted to call the `set_password` method, but it failed. The same error. I used `User = apps.get_registered_model('auth', 'User')`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this method return `"%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)`. So, maybe use:

```
def my_get_full_name(user):
    return "%s %s" % (user.first_name, user.last_name)

full_name = my_get_full_name(user)
```

I had a similar problem. I needed a `set_password` method. But, I found that this method uses `make_password` function from `django.contrib.auth.hashers`. So, `user.password = make_password('pass')` works.

Comment: Thanks! I manually wrote a method to deal with it. Just curious, why cannot use it directly?